# Java NetBeans8 connect to HTTP mysql database

Tags: java, netbeans

how to connect http (Web Hosting) mysql database from Java Netbeans8?
I use jdbc Driver.

```
package javaswimingapplication;

public class JavaSwimingApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();
        connect.getData();
    }

}
```

---

```
package javaswimingapplication;

import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnect {
    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public DBConnect(){
        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://web server ip/database name","database user","password");
            st = con.createStatement();

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
        }
    }

    public void getData(){
        try{

            String query = "select * from persons";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("Rexords from database");
            while(rs.next()){
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String age = rs.getString("age");
                //String name = rs.getString("name");

                System.out.println("Name: "+name+"  "+"Age: "+age);
            }


        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Error:

run:

Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
java.lang.NullPointerException
СБОРКА УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНА (общее время: 22 секунды)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that MySQL server listening on its external ip or probably just on localhost or even local socketfile?

Most MySQL servers provided along with webspace are configured to be unaccessible from an external network.

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//91.212.89.57/tutorials_uz_employe", "tutor_employe", "K8cns9#2");
            st = con.createStatement();

Comment: Error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//91.212.89.57/tutorials_uz_employe
java.lang.NullPointerException
СБОРКА УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНА (общее время: 0 секунд)

Comment: First and foremost: Did you just post credentials for the database? And the error message suggests that now you are missing the MySQL Connector library in your classpath or the DB server is not listening on its default port or (as I said in my first comment) not listening on its external IP at all.